# Google indexing wrong URL on mobile search

Tags: php, wordpress, url, mobile, indexing

I have a wordpress website @ www.mutantspace.com and on mobile search google is putting 'mobile friendly' infront of my URLs  on keyword searches i.e. 'Ronald Hall Paintings'. However it isnt a mobile friendly website and google is indexing a bizarre URL which only redirects users to the home page and not the website:

On mobile search for 'Ronald Hall Paintings' the url is http://www.mutsntspace.com/#article/64393 (the number refers to post ID) 
On desktop search for 'Ronald Hall Paintings' the url is http://www.mutantspace.com/ronald-hall-paintings-re-appropriate-historical-narratives-race/

I use wordpress. This is very strange and i dont know how it fix it...can someone help or advise please.....
thanks
Moray

Answer (score 0):

This just looks like an indexing error on Google's end. Have you updated your sitemap and submitted into google webmasters? That's the fastest way of helping Google crawl your website.

Nice pictures btw! :)

Comment: I have updated sitemap - over on google forum it was suggested i add the follwing code into the header which would redirect all mobile searches to desktop. The code is: <script>
if (window.location.hash && (m = window.location.hash.match(/article\/(\d+)/))) {
 window.location.href = '?p="+m[1];
}
</script> Would that work or is there another way i can redirect mobile searches to desktop?

Comment: that would work, but it might not be the best practise to redirect mobile traffic to desktop since all your mobile articles will be redirected to their desktop version. 
Google takes a few days to update their links, so I'd say the best thing is to wait a bit and see if the link disappears (which it should since the sitemap was updated)

Comment: okay thanks thing is i dont have a mobile site so i want google mobile search to redirect to desktop version....anyway ill wait and see....i have put that script in but redirect isnt working....

Comment: you can temporairly add in a mobile site by isntalling wptouch. its a wordpress plugin that makes your website mobile friendly!

Comment: i did that originally but none of them really do the job...although i am tempted to put it in again and see what happens problem is my website is an art site and so is image heavy so its not that good on mobile